# Binary Search - A list of filenames from a different list of files

Tags: python, binary-search

I am trying to implement a Binary Search in Python. I have two lists,
list1 = [filename1-10-22, filename2-10-22, filename3-10-22] and
list2 = [filename1-9-22, filename2-9-22, filename3-9-22, filename1-10-22, filename2-10-22, filename3-10-22]
And I want to search the files present in both the lists and add it in a separate list.
This is the Code I have so far:

```
    list1 = [filename1-10-22, filename2-10-22, filename3-10-22]
    list2 = [filename1-9-22, filename2-9-22, filename3-9-22, filename1-10-22, filename2-10-22, filename3-10-22]    
    xmls_already_processed_list = []
    new_files_check_list = []
    for fileName in list1:
     start = 0
     end = len(list2) - 1
     while start <= end:
         middle = (start + end)// 2
         midpoint = list2[middle]
         if midpoint == fileName:
          xmls_already_processed_list.append((filePath,fileName))
         elif midpoint > fileName: 
          end = middle - 1
         elif midpoint < fileName:
          start = middle + 1
         else:
          new_files_check_list.append(fileName)
```

I am unable to filter the files, and I dont want to use a linear search because it is an extensive operation because the length of lists will increase in coming days.

Comment: what happens when you run the program?

Comment: It is not adding any filenames to my array xmls_already_processed_list. It is not working below the point where  - midpoint > fileName (How can I compare two Strings?)